# Modular Programming in R

Tags: r, function, module, package

Quite new to R, I am wondering if it is possible to shrink own blowed-up R scripts by packaging parts into sub scripts, like modules or global own functions. This is somewhat usual in other interpreter languages.

What is the best way split data-reading, plotting, designing, exporting, etc in different R modules?

Comment: R has its package system for that purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can make subscripts containing functions for example and use `source` to source them.

I think the best way to do this depends on the case, but just write your functions, save them as .R files and `source` them in your script

Answer (score 8):

There’s a package for exactly this purpose, called ‘[box](https://klmr.me/box/)’.

The package provides a function `box::use()` which replaces `source` and `library` in a smart manner.

```
source('x.r')
```

can simply be replaced by

```
box::use(./x)
# or:
box::use(./x[...]) # to attach all names
```

However, `box::use()` does many things better than `source` — for instance, you can organise your modules hierarchically inside a project, you can treat package and module code uniformly, you can document your module code, and more.

[See the vignette for details](https://klmr.me/box/articles/box.html).

The ‘box’ package was created precisely because I was unsatisfied with R’s support for modularisation.

Comment: I get Error in importCheckInstall(pkg) : 'package:x.R' is not installed! even when source("x.R") works. I alternatively tried modules::use("x.R"), which does load, but then it doesn't recognize tidyverse %>% when actually calling x.R.

Comment: @yakzo I realise that your comment is by now quite old and outdated with release of version 1.0, but this problem is now addressed [in the FAQ](https://klmr.me/box/articles/faq.html#-there-is-no-package-called-foo-when-running-box-use-foo-even-though-the-module-foo-exists).